# Why is my system using my old PYTHONPATH after explicitly setting?

Tags: python, collision, pythonpath, setting

I am running a script that explicitly sets the PYTHONPATH to avoid naming collisions. However, even if I say `os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = ''`, it looks as though the system is still able to find my old path that "lives" outside the script.

How is my system able to see the old PYTHONPATH even after I explicitly set it to a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is parsed at startup and inserted into `sys.path`. If you need to adjust the path from within your Python code, manipulate `sys.path`, not `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: You're a life-saver. That was driving me crazy!